# Rust: Array を定数で満たす場合

Tags: rust

Rust の質問です. 以下のコードはコンパイルエラーになります.

```
fn main() {
    let a = 100;
    let b = [0; a];
}
```

エラー:

```
let b = [0; a];
            ^ unresolved path in constant expression
```

`let a` してるのに, どうして `a` が解決されていないとされてしまってるのでしょうか. よろしくお願いします.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rustの配列は実行時にサイズを指定できません。`a`の場所には定数式（constant expression）だけが書けます。

定数式を使った例：

```
// 定数式ならコンパイルできる。
fn main() {
    let c = [0; 100];
    let d = [0; 5 * 10];
}
```

実行時にサイズが指定できない理由は、配列の要素がスタックに格納されるからです。Rustではスタックに置く値のサイズは、コンパイル時に決まっていないといけません。

もし実行時にサイズを指定したいのなら、Vec（ベクタ）の利用を検討してください。

```
// ベクタなら実行時にサイズを指定できる。
fn main() {
    let a = 100;
    let b = vec![0; a];
}
```

ベクタの要素はヒープに格納されます。スタックに置く場合と異なり、値のサイズは実行時に決められます。

---

**追記**

`const` を使うと定数に名前を付けられます。

```
const A: usize = 100;

fn main() {
    let b = [0; A];
}
```

Comment: なるほど. 「スタックに確保するサイズは、コンパイル時に決まっていないといけない」制約に引っかかってますね. Rust 難しい...